# Observe any change to sharedUserDefaultsController values

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults

is there any way to observe any change to `[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController]`?

I know I can observe a single value but I'd rather consolidate all these individual observers into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` notification.